# How to Remove or Reduce white space between Header and Post Title

Tags: wordpress, footer

I have found the element that I need to modify. However, I don't know where in the theme file or what to put in the additional css to change the padding values. Does anyone know how I might remove or reduce this space? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do that, go to Appearance → Customize → Additional CSS and enter the following code:

```
.site-header {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

You could also try like this:

```
#page {

margin: 2em auto;

}
```

CHANGE: 2em to 0em and you’ll have removed the space.

Comment: thank you for the reply Jose- I added this to the additional CSS and am still getting that space. Any other ideas?

Comment: Answered edited, lets try like that

Comment: thank you again Jose! Sadly, no luck on the additional CSS. I really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it after inspecting the element, and literally copying the element into the additional css and reducing the padding.